# Check if text appears on the text property of any element in SelectList

Tags: c#, .net, selectlist, selectlistitem

```
SelectList tempList =
    Chatham.Web.Models.Shared.DropDownData.IndicationsGroup(
        SessionManager.Company.EntityID,
        ICConstants.IndicationsCalculatorGroupType);

foreach (SelectListItem item in tempList)
{
    if (value.ToString() == item.Value)
    {
        if (item.Text == "Create a New Group")
        {
            GroupDisplayName = "";
            break;
        }
        GroupDisplayName = item.Text;
        break;
    }
}
```

On the line where it clears the previously set value: `GroupDisplayName = "";`, I instead want it to check what that previously set text was, and if that text IS IN one of the `text` properties of the items in `tempList`, that's the only time it should clear it.

Edit:

I know I could do this by looping through every element, but I am already within a loop of the same exact type, so I would not want to increase complexity this much. I was hoping there was some sort on LINQ query or something I could use, or something along the lines of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (tempList.Select(i => i.Text).Contains(GroupDisplayName))
     // do the rest
```

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was looking for, however I am getting this error when I go to compile: Error 50 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) -- does this type of syntax only work on generic lists?

Comment: have you added `using System.Linq`?